# Getting $head_title in my module

Tags: hooks

I am building a module that requires me to get the $head_title variable in the hook_node_view for some processing...I have found info about that variable in relation to themes and around core, but not getting it in a module...I have successfully used drupal_get_title(), and variable_get() to get info, but I can not figure out how to get $head_title...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

`$head_title` is one of the variables passed to the [html.tpl.php](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7) template file, and set from [template_preprocess_html()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/template_preprocess_html/7).

```
  // Construct page title.
  if (drupal_get_title()) {
    $head_title = array(
      'title' => strip_tags(drupal_get_title()), 
      'name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')),
    );
  }
  else {
    $head_title = array('name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')));
    if (variable_get('site_slogan', '')) {
      $head_title['slogan'] = filter_xss_admin(variable_get('site_slogan', ''));
    }
  }
  $variables['head_title_array'] = $head_title;
  $variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', $head_title);
```

That variable would be available as `$variables['head_title']`, if your module implements `hook_preprocess_html()` or `hook_process_html()`. Otherwise, you just need to execute similar code to the one used by [template_preprocess_html()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/template_preprocess_html/7). To adapt that code for a module, outside `hook_preprocess_html()` and `hook_process_html()`, I would rewrite it as follows.

```
  // Construct page title.
  if (drupal_get_title()) {
    $head_title = array(
      'title' => strip_tags(drupal_get_title()), 
      'name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')),
    );
  }
  else {
    $head_title = array('name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')));
    if (variable_get('site_slogan', '')) {
      $head_title['slogan'] = filter_xss_admin(variable_get('site_slogan', ''));
    }
  }

  // Remove the following line if you just need the string.
  $head_title_array = $head_title;

  $head_title = implode(' | ', $head_title);
```